# how do I enable POJO-mapping programatically in Jersey using Grizzly2?

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly

Following the instructions [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#getting-started) I have this code:

```
private static URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();
}

public static final URI BASE_URI = getBaseURI();

protected static HttpServer startServer() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Starting grizzly...");
    final ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("amplify.api.resources");
    return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final HttpServer httpServer = startServer();
    System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
            + "%sapplication.wadl\nTry out %shelloworld\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI, BASE_URI));
    System.in.read();
    httpServer.stop();
}
```

Next I want to enable JSON POJO support as described [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json.pojo.approach.section), but the problem is that I want to do it programmatically rather than through a web.xml file (I don't have a web.xml file!).

How can I modify the code above to enable the JSON POJO mapping feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
protected static HttpServer startServer() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Starting grizzly...");
    final ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("amplify.api.resources");
    rc.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);
    return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add jersey-json library to your project.

If you are using maven, just add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This works for me even without adding JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING to the ResourceConfig's feautres.