# How do I programmatically configure Jersey to use Jackson for JSON (de)serialization?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, grizzly

I'm using Jersey together with Grizzly to create a JSON web service.  I initialize it as follows:

```
    final ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("amplify.api.resources");
    rc.getProperties().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);
    return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
```

I have no web.xml file.  I noticed that Jersey was mapping single element lists to be "element" rather than "[element]" as I would expect.  It seems that apparently this is because Jersey uses a POJO->JSON mapper other than Jackson, and for reasons that elude me, they thought it would be a great idea to automatically unwrap single-element lists.

I found explanations of how to make Jersey use Jackson by configuring the web.xml file, but since I don't have a web.xml, I'm unsure how to do this.

Can anyone explain how I can programmatically configure Jersey to use Jackson?

Answer (score 1):

I have response from [how do I enable POJO-mapping programatically in Jersey using Grizzly2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490123/how-do-i-enable-pojo-mapping-programatically-in-jersey-using-grizzly2/14373174#14373174)

The idea is to add jersey-json library to your application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `JacksonJsonProvider` in [the Jackson jax-rs module](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#JAX-RS).

You need to hook it (or a subclass such as `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`) in the Jersey-recognized IoC container (its own by default, but I personally prefer Guice), or otherwise get it registered as an `@Provider`

Comment: Huh? One of the best ways to use Jersey is using IoC.  So much better than web.xml or wiring by hand!

Comment: +1: I got what I wanted using exactly this approach, with Guice.  See this blog post: http://www.flamingpenguin.co.uk/blog/2012/08/17/use-new-version-of-jackson-json-with-jersey/